# Convert float to string with dynamic precision - python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, precision

I want to convert float value (with dynamic precision) to string 
if float value which i am getting **a = 10.00** than result should be **'10.00'**
and if  **a = 10.000** than result should be *'10.000'*

I am getting result like this

```
a = 10.00
str(a)
'10.0'
```

But I want result like this.

```
a = 10.00
str(a)
'10.00'
```

Is there any way ?

Comment: BTW, assuming that `.` is a decimal point and not digit grouping, `a=10.00` and `a=10.000` are exactly the same value, no possibility to distinguish the two.

Comment: Maybe `10.00` and `10.000` are just a badly chosen example, but currently you are asking for a function that will return `y` if the input is `x`, but `z` if the input is `x`.

Comment: ya sorry for that but let me explain 
its not about 10.00 or 10.000
    
**i am talking about dynamic float value with dynamic precision**

Comment: @tobias_k yes, i know 10.00 and 10.000 is same but is that possible to get that same value in string format

Comment: We understood that part about dynamic precision the first three times you said it, but we will need a better example or more explanation as to what you really want to have. Just put in a few numbers and show how they should be formatted. And try not to make all those numbers the same number.

Comment: Let me explain one scenario where I am allowing user to enter input from command line, say for example user enter 10.00, I want both 0's after decimal, currently amount becomes 10.0
Checkout this in python shell, a = 10.00 now when you convert it into string it becomes 10.0 and my situation is I do not want to loose 0's, whatever user enters I want that value, note that I am accepting only numbers from user input(I do not want to allow string input, so do not give answer that take string value as input :))

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to preserve significant digits, then use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> num1 = Decimal('10.000')
>>> str(num1)
'10.000'
>>> num2 = Decimal('10.00')
>>> str(num2)
'10.00'
```

The decimal module does support decimal floating point arithmetic.

```
>>> num1/5
Decimal('2.000')
>>> num1+22
Decimal('32.000')
```

Comment: You are giving string value as input

Comment: @SwapneshShah See my comment. As a `float`, `10.000` and `10.00` are indistinguisable.

Comment: @SwapneshShah - You want some thing like this `print "%.2f" % a` where output will be `10.00` irrespective of whether `a=10.00` or `a=10.000`?

Comment: @SwapneshShah - Do read his comment and think on your question a bit.

Comment: @ Jason Estibeiro I don't want to remove decimal precision during converting to string

Comment: @SwapneshShah - You'll have to take input using string if you want to preserve the significant digits. Have a look at tobias_k's answer. The value of `a` will always be `10.0` even if you set `a=10.00` or `a=10.000` or `a=10.0000`.

Answer (score 3):

```
# way 1
a = 10.00
s = '%.2f' % a
print s # 10.00

# way 2
a = 10.0
p = 2
s = '%.{0}f'.format(p) % a
print s # 10.00
```

Comment: but it is static up to two precision i am having dynamic precision

Comment: Float numbers don't contain information about how many zeros are after the point. In other words 10.0 always equals to 10.000. To keep a certain accuracy you have to store it in a separate variable and use it as a parameter to convert into a string you need. I added another way to solve your problem in my answer

Comment: In Python 3, you can use f-strings in "way 2" as `s = f'{a:.{p}f}'`.

Answer (score 1):

> i am getting a = 10.00 than result should be '10.00' and if a = 10.000 than result should be '10.000'
>
> if 'a = 5.500 than str(a) should be '5.500' if 'a = 10.50 than str(a) should be '10.50' if 'a = 1.050 than str(a) should be '1.050'

What you are asking for is not possible. Not in Python, and not in any other programming language that I know of. If `a` is a regular floating point number, then `10.0` is the same as `10.00` or `10.000`. They are all stored the same and have the same precision.

```
>>> a = 5.500
>>> b = 5.5
>>> c = 5.500000000
>>> a == b == c
True
```

The only way to circumvent this, is not to use `float`, but another type, like `Decimal`, as suggested in another answer.

> Let me explain one scenario where I am allowing user to enter input from command line, say for example user enter 10.00, I want both 0's after decimal, currently amount becomes 10.0

According to your last comment, you get the numbers from a text input, i.e. as `str`, so it should be no problem to use `decimal`. But if you just want to echo those numbers back to the user, you don't need even that: Just print the string the user originally entered.

> note that I am accepting only numbers from user input(I do not want to allow string input

You can just get string input and convert that input to a number. Problem solved.

```
>>> s = raw_input("enter number ")
enter number 10.000
>>> f = float(s)
>>> s
'10.000'
>>> f
10.0
```

Comment: Note that I am getting number(Float) not string

Comment: @SwapneshShah You just told us that you are getting the number from user input, so you _can_ just change that to receive a string instead, and convert it to a number afterwards, instead of insisting on the _impossible_ task to take a number and converting it back to the original string the user entered.

Comment: You say you are getting the number using `input()` in Python 2.7. So the user could also enter `5. * 2` or `100**.5` or `1e1` and all those will evaluate to `10.0`. There is _no way_ you can decide what the user entered from just the number. Just change to `raw_input` and convert to `float` afterwards`